# captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection is delayed

Tags: ios, camera

I use the code below to capture an image. I have the call to this routine in a loop with a 3 second timer, so I capture an image every 3 seconds. This usually works fine but sometimes the captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection() method gets executed and the program just sits there for 10 - 20 seconds with nothing obvious going on. Then it resumes normal operation, capturing an image every 3 seconds. What would cause this delay to happen?

```
- (void)captureStillImage
{
    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", [self stillImageOutput]);

    if ( videoConnection ) {

        waitingForCapture = true;

        NSLog(@"requesting a capture from: %@", [self stillImageOutput]);
        [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                                         completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

            if ( imageSampleBuffer ) {

                CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
                if (exifAttachments) {
                    NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"no attachments");
                }

                NSLog(@"name: %@", [currentCaptureDevice localizedName]);

                NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                [self setStillImage:image];


                NSDictionary *dict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)exifAttachments;
                NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"PixelXDimension"];
                [self setImageWidth:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[value intValue]]];

                value = [dict objectForKey:@"PixelYDimension"];
                [self setImageHeight:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[value intValue]]];

                value = [dict objectForKey:@"BrightnessValue"];
                [self setImageBrightnessValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[value floatValue]]];

                value = [dict objectForKey:@"ShutterSpeedValue"];
                double val = [value doubleValue];
                val = 1.0 / pow(2.0, val);
                [self setImageExposureTime:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:val]];

                value = [dict objectForKey:@"ApertureValue"];
                [self setImageApertureValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[value floatValue]]];

                NSArray *values = [dict objectForKey:@"ISOSpeedRatings"];
                [self setImageISOSpeedRatings:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[ [values objectAtIndex:0] intValue]]];


                NSLog(@"r/g/b gains = %.2lf/%.2lf/%.2lf",
                      currentCaptureDevice.deviceWhiteBalanceGains.redGain,
                      currentCaptureDevice.deviceWhiteBalanceGains.greenGain,
                      currentCaptureDevice.deviceWhiteBalanceGains.blueGain);


                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kImageCapturedSuccessfully object:nil];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"imageSampleBuffer = NULL");
            }

            waitingForCapture = false;

         }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"can't capture from: videoConnection");
    }

}
```

here is how I kick it off:

```
-(void)startContinuousPhotometry
{
    progressView.progress = 0.0f;
    if ( ![self checkCameraStatus]) {
        return;
    }

    continueRunning = true;
    backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("test", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_set_target_queue(backgroundQueue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));
    [self process];

}


-(void)process {
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {
        [self live];
    });
}


-(void)live
{

    while ( continueRunning ) {

        if ( [self isCameraChangingSettings] ) {
            NSLog(@"adjusting exposure");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NOT adjusting exposure");
        }

        if ( ![[self captureManager] getWaitingForCapture]) {
            [[self captureManager] captureStillImage];
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:LOOP_PAUSE_TIME_S];
        } else {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; // wait 1 second
            NSLog(@"waiting for getWaitingForCapture");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are calling an `asynchronous` function. Its execution time is not guaranteed. The processor may choose to delay its execution while running higher-priority tasks.

Comment: can I raise the priority so it runs first?

Comment: when I look at the cpu usage in xcode it never goes above 37%, there are only 13 threads running and when the captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection is waiting the cpu drops to 0 and there is no activity on any of the other threads.

Comment: It's possible that it's waiting on acquiring a hardware lock for the image capture device. I don't really know much about the process that you're invoking, but generally when things are marked asynchronous, it's because the length of time the process takes on average is not small (or predictable). Network requests, for instance, are almost always asynchronous because there's no way to guarantee latency across a physical distance of cables.

Comment: I've added the code that I make the thread which calls  captureStillImage()

Comment: I've looked at the AVCamManualUsingtheManualCaptureAPI example. This also delays but not for as long as mine. I made my code almost the same as in the AVCamManualUsingtheManualCaptureAPI example with no noticeable improvement.